# How do I get to alternate versions of the tutorial?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft, on the XBOX360. 
There is a tutorial at my dad's house, but I cant find that tutorial at my mom's house. How can I get to alternate versions of the tutorial.

The tutorial I want, has this castle in the tutorial:

[image]

--Transcribed by an adult.

Comment: What is this tutorial? Where is it from? How do you access it? - explain I more detail please

Answer (score 1):

you can go to your storage on your xbox device you can find (something like) a folder that named minecraft klick on it and delete the title update, when a setup starts while you play it an it asks for an update just press [NO]